# Update a column of table with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle I need to Update a Column of a Table with `ROW_NUMBER()` in oracle

i.e

```
UPDATE tablefull
SET newcolumn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnid ORDER BY datecolumn)-1
```

Since the Window function is not allowed in Update I had tried with joining the table with subquery of same table and do the update

```
update a
set a.newcolumn= b.upnum
from tablefull a
INNER JOIN (SELECT columnid,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnid ORDER BY datecolumn)-1 AS upnum 
FROM tablefull) b ON b.columnid=a.columnid
```

Since the join and update is also not possible in oracle the above also did not worked out

Please anyone help me in the way to update the newcolumn of the table with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnid ORDER BY datecolumn)-1` in Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this query with `row_number` as source table of `merge` statement:

```
merge into tablefull tgt
using (select rowid rwd, columnid, 
              row_number() over (partition by columnid order by datecolumn) - 1 rn
         from tablefull) src
on (src.rwd = tgt.rowid and tgt.columnid = src.columnid)
when matched then update set newcolumn = rn;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=380efb1211693b5b12b0030d85145499)</sup>**